# Pdf Document Link control error - PdfDocumentLink.ascx

Tags: sitefinity

I just upgraded from 5.1 to 7.0 and now I am getting this error on one of the pages that have a PdfDocumentLink control (in Edit Mode):

A required control was not found in the template for "~/Sitefinity/Extensions/WidgetTemplates/Libraries/Documents/PdfDocumentLink.ascx". The control must be assignable from type "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl" and must have ID "itemsContainer".

I get a 500 in Preview mode.

This is the code for the ascx, in \Sitefinity\Extensions\WidgetTemplates\Libraries\Documents

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sitefinity" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.BrowseAndEdit" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<sitefinity:ResourceLinks id="resourcesLinks2" runat="server" UseEmbeddedThemes="false" Theme="Default">

  <sitefinity:ResourceFile Name="~/Sitefinity/Extensions/WidgetTemplates/Libraries/Documents/PdfDocumentLink.css" Static="true"  /> 
</sitefinity:ResourceLinks>
<sitefinity:SitefinityHyperLink ID="documentLink" runat="server" target="_blank" CssClass="PdfDocumentLink" />
<sf:BrowseAndEditToolbar ID="browseAndEditToolbar" runat="server" Mode="Edit"></sf:BrowseAndEditToolbar>
```

Here's the cs file ... under C:\inetpub\xxx\App_Code\Widgets

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace xxx.Sitefinity.Widgets.Libraries.Documents {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PdfDocumentLink
    /// </summary>
    public class PdfDocumentLink : Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.UI.Documents.DocumentLink {
        public PdfDocumentLink() : base () {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public override string LayoutTemplatePath {
            get {
                return "~/Sitefinity/Extensions/WidgetTemplates/Libraries/Documents/PdfDocumentLink.ascx";
            }
            set {
                base.LayoutTemplatePath = value;
            }
        }

        public string LinkTitle {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            if (this.LinkTitle != null)
            this.DocumentLinkControl.Text = this.LinkTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

And ToolboxesConfig.config file:

```
  ...
    <toolboxesConfig xmlns:config="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration" xmlns:type="urn:telerik:sitefinity:configuration:type" config:version="7.0.5100.0">
        <toolboxes>
            <toolbox name="PageControls">
                <sections>
                    <add name="ContentToolboxSection">
                        <tools>...
                            <add enabled="True" type="OneCommand.Sitefinity.Widgets.Libraries.Documents.PdfDocumentLink" title="PDF Document Link" description="Link to a PDF Document" cssClass="sfDownloadLinkIcn" moduleName="Libraries" Name="PDFDocumentLink" visibilityMode="None" name="PDFDocumentLink" />
```

If I delete the widget, and add it back in, and select a pdf document, I get the same error.

The Document Link widget appears to work ok, but that one doesn't have the left side PDF icon that we want to display.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm able to recreate this and it looks like you're adding in a LinkTitle attribute to the default DocumentLink control. Can you just use the default one and change the title of the document: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/user-guide/widgets/content-widgets-group/configuring-the-document-link-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your .ascx file:

```
<div runat="server" id="itemsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Any ideas why this DIV is needed now, and it wasn't needed before?

Comment: If you view the source of the page, it looks like that control adds in an icon class to the div, depending on what icon type you chose in the settings of the widget, which is used to show the appropriate icon on the anchor. You might not be seeing the icon because in your ascx file you're overriding the default styles with some custom ones. If you download the Sitefinity SDK, the vanilla DocumentLink template is in there and you can compare.